# How to show all data in Highchart

Tags: javascript, datetime, charts, highcharts

How do I ensure that the data are close to each other & sorting by datetime. I want show all data with datetime

```js
var charts = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'area',
    data: [
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 00), 3.500],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 02), 3.501],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 04), 3.502],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 06), 3.505],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 08), 3.509],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 10), 3.507],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 12), 3.510],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 14), 3.525],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 16), 3.536],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 18), 3.575],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 20), 3.595],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 22), 3.514],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 24), 3.525],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 26), 3.536],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 28), 3.514],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 30), 3.510],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 32), 3.523],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 25, 14, 13, 34), 3.596],
      [Date.UTC(2015, 9, 26, 18, 13, 34), 4.596]
    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is you have a lot of points within a few seconds, and then a point an entire day away. 'datetime' plot may not be the best option for this type of application.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Z. Bagley wrote, to resolve this problem you can use couple solutions. The first one would be concerning using Highstock chart. In Highstock chart there is a property called `ordinal` (true by default) which distributes points equally on xAxis. Secondly, you can use `breaks` along with setting a new xAxis extremes to decrease distance between the last two dates. You can also try to add a `scrollbar`.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/scrollbar

Examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/pbdor59x/ - using Highstock and ordinal property
http://jsfiddle.net/abwpqs19/ - using breaks
http://jsfiddle.net/4cc2n3sp/ - using scrollbar